# Is there any open source project of image compression and load image?

Tags: open-source

Is there any open source project/lbrary of image compression and load image?

I know many image website, when user upload image, it will be compress to `1080H`, `1200W`, `1920W`, `480H` or other specifications.

when load image, it will load a low quality specification such as `480H`, when click to enlarge, it will load a high quality specification.

Answer (score 1):

One common way of implementing the higher resolution image on click is to simply have the low resolution image as the embedded image but with a link to the higher resolution image. The other possibility is to use an incremental rendering or [progressive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_download) format that will load and display at a lower resolution initially and then gain detail as it loads.

For preparing the images at the various resolutions or for incremental/progressive loading there are numerous FOSS options to consider:

- [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/index.php) provides numerous command line or batch file conversion & manipulation options.
- [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) if you are in a python workflow Pillow is often the go to library for image manipulation. Being python based it is easy to script repeated operations.
- [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) the GNU Image Manipulation Program is a GUI program that can export images in a number of formats, compressions & sizes.
- [G'MIC](https://gmic.eu/) Greys Magic for Image Computing provides a range of command line, GUI, Library, Plug-In & Web options for image manipulations including resizing.
- [Darktable](https://www.darktable.org/) - is a complete photographic workflow, including resizing & compression to various file formats.

All of the above are Free, Gratis & Open Source, cross platform and well worth looking at for other uses as well.